# Android emulator halt the system after I upgrade to Mac 10.9

Tags: osx-mavericks

Android emulator halt the system after I upgrade to Mac 10.9. (I ran the android emulator from Android studio).

Actually my page or preview will halt the system in Mac 10.9 in my another machine (iMac).

Does anybody have the same problem? Any solutions? Thanks

Comment: Any idea? I did everything. But system just still freeze when I turn on the android emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the intel emulator. They've fixed the issue already.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455134/running-android-virtual-devices-2-3-3-or-4-3-versions-in-mac-os-10-9-halt-my-sys/23661054#23661054