# Running Android Virtual Devices 2.3.3 or 4.3 versions in Mac OS 10.9 halt my system

Tags: android, macos, virtual, osx-mavericks, device

I've tried to run several times in Mac OS 10.9 and my system halt when I Android emulator starts. I don't know how to solve that problem. The only solution when it happens is switch off my laptop.
Any ideas are welcomed.

Comment: Alternatively, I suggest you to try [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) and it's really fast.

Answer (score 0):

Intel released a fix for Mavericks OS X 10.9 on 11/06/2013.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/11/06/intelr-haxm-hot-ffixes-for-os-x-mavericks-109-and-windows-81-available-for

```
Intel(R) Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) Version 1.0.7 Hot fixes for OS X Mavericks (10.9) and Windows 8.1 has  just been published in the HAXM webpage

This software:
-Uses Intel VT, available on select Intel processors
-Provides hardware-accelerated emulation of Intel(R) x86 Android virtual devices
-Integrates with the Android SDK...

Known issue:
The Android Emulator may freeze when HAXM and VirtualBox v4.2.14 and newer are run in parallel on the same machine. Our testing shows that previous versions of VirtualBox, v4.2.12 and earlier, don’t exhibit the issue.
```